# Two different versions of Vue in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, vuejs3

I built my application using Vue3, now deploying it to Laravel.

However, I would like to make an administration panel for it, but I do not want to waste time creating a new template for it, but I want to use a ready-made template from the Internet. However, I have a problem because the all of available templates are based on the older version of VueJS 2.X.

What can I do? Can I somehow use two versions of VueJS with Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

To create a Vue app, we need to use a special createApp function instead of ... will still install Vue 2.x and npm i vue@next will install Vue 3.